# Sinatra datamapper extracting information from a certain entry

Tags: sinatra, limit, datamapper

I'm new to Sinatra and I want to create a service for a mobile application.  I've created a small project that records entries into the datamapper, and am able to extract all the information and return a json object.  The problem is, is that as you add in more data to the database the response will get larger and will take a while to download on a mobile device.  So I would like to extract the data in a different way, by giving it the Serial id, I would like to only extract the next 10 entries based on completed_at time (see below).

```
class NewsObject
  include DataMapper::Resource  
  property :id,           Serial
  property :title,         String
  property :completed_at, DateTime, :default => DateTime.now
end
```

So far I'm manged to extract the information in the correct order and limit the response (see below), I just need to figure out how to start at a certain Serial id

NewsObject.all(:order => [:completed_at], :limit => 2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
NewsObject.all(:order => [:completed_at], :limit => 2, :id.gte => my_id)
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks for you help.  Do you know of any link that shows a list of these key words

Comment: DataMapper's documentation is not exactly the best I've ever seen, but you can find a lot of information [here](http://datamapper.org/docs/find.html). Please don't forget to mark my answer as correct ;)

Comment: @user863238 IF this answer solved your problem, click on the checkbox near it to select it as the official answer. This way you are helping other guys to find a solution.